# Reverse a array in Golang without changing the negative number positions

Tags: arrays, go

I want to reverse an array without changing the negative number positions. Below is the program I tried & I am missing some simple logic here. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 package main
 import "fmt"
 func swapContents1(listObj []int) {
   i, j := 0, len(listObj)-1
    for i < j {
    if listObj[i] < 0 {
         i++
    }
    if listObj[j] < 0 {
        j--
    }
    listObj[i], listObj[j] = listObj[j], listObj[i]
    i++
    j--
   }
 }

func main() {

  listObj := []int{1, 2, 3, -4, 5, -6, -7}

  swapContents1(listObj)

  fmt.Println(listObj)
}
```

Expected Output : [5 3 2 -4 1 -6 -7]

Output I got : [-6 5 3 -4 2 1 -7]

Comment: What problem did you encounter?

Comment: @JonathanHall desired output is not coming as there is some indexing problem I believe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were pretty close, you only need to add `continue` after conditionals that check if number is negative. So your `swapContents1` function would look like this:

```
func swapContents1(listObj []int) {
    i, j := 0, len(listObj)-1
    for i < j {
        if listObj[i] < 0 {
            i++
            continue
        }
        if listObj[j] < 0 {
            j--
            continue
        }
        listObj[i], listObj[j] = listObj[j], listObj[i]
        i++
        j--
    }
}
```